# Formar una cadena python

Tags: python, impresión

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que me permita crear una palabra, mediante letras ingresadas por el usuario (Se supone que ingresa letras de a una por vez).

Lo hice usando una lista, pero cuando imprimo me aparece: `['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']`, y lo que **no quiero que me aparezcan las comillas ni las comas.**
Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Esto es lo q hice:

```
palabra=[]
letra=str(input("Ingrese la primer letra de la palabra")) 
while letra!="/":
    palabra.append(letra)
    letra=str(input("Ingrese la primer letra de la palabra"))

print(palabra)
```

Comment: Simplemente usa `str.join` : `print("".join(palabra))`, si no puedes pues concatena cadenas en el `while`. Por cierto, si usas Python 3 `input` ya retorna una cadena, el casting a `str` no es necesario. Si usas Python 2 no uses `input` para entradas de usuario sin filtrar (es peligroso), usa `raw_input` que también retorna una cadena.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahi pude! Y si quiero concatenar las cadenas enn el while como hago'

Comment: Declaras la cadena vacía antes del `while` como haces ahora con la lista `palabra = ''`,  luego dentro del `while` concatenas : `palabra += letra` (donde usas ahora `append`). La concatenación de cadenas es ineficiente ya que son inmutables y concatenar implica crear un nuevo objeto, aunque en estos programas no importa demasiado esto :).

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es que en tu bucle `while`, en vez de guardar las letras en una lista, las añadas al final de la cadena de caracteres y esto se puede hacer con el signo `+`, que usado entre dos caracteres, lo que hace es concatenar. Tu código quedaría así

```
#Inicializas palabra como una cadena de caracteres vacía
palabra=''
letra=str(input("Ingrese la primer letra de la palabra")) 

while letra!="/":
    #Concatenas cada letra a la palabra
    palabra = palabra + letra
    letra=str(input("Ingrese la primer letra de la palabra"))

print(palabra)
```

Y el resultado del print verás que es `hola` si las letras que añades son `h`, `o`, `l` y `a`

Answer (score 0):

Como opción usa el método [.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) de esta forma para eliminar comillas y comas:

```
print(' '.join(palabra))
```

de esta forma en lugar de obtener `['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']` , obtendrás como salida:

```
h o l a
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui se digita las letras, cada una separada por enter, y para no ingresar mas letras simplemente se da enter cuando este vacio y ya.

```
from sys import stdin

w=[]
while True:
    b=input()
    if b:
        w.append(b)
    else:
        break
a=('')
for i in w:
    a=a+str(i)
print(a)
```